# Telerik radgridview Pagination

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I want to implement pagination in telerik radgridview for vb.net windows form. Instead of assign the datasource one time, I want to get data from mysql on each pagination per page so that it is fast in retrieving data. How can i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadGridView supports client-side paging. Hence, RadGridView has a DataSource applied to it which stores all records and the data is represented in multiple pages:  https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/paging/overview

However, if you want to load data on-demand, it is appropriate to use RadVirtualGrid which also supports paging. The following help articles are quite useful about getting familiar with the control and how to populate it with data:
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/virtualgrid/overview
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/virtualgrid/working-with-data/virtualgrid-populating-with-data
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/virtualgrid/paging/paging-overview

Comment: Is there example how I can assign datasource per page in RadVirtualGrid?

Comment: RadVirtualGrid populates its data via the CellValueNeeded event. Whenever a cell value is requested, the event is fired and it is necessary to specify the Value considering the RowIndex/ColumnIndex. Please refer to the below help articles: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/virtualgrid/working-with-data/virtualgrid-populating-with-data

Comment: You can refer to the Telerik WinForms Demo application >> VirtualGrid >> Paging example: https://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx